# magento 2 custom email template image/logo not displayed

Tags: magento2.2, email-templates, static-content, logo

I am custom template for Magento 2
Created two new email template in admin backend

1. order confirmation email template
2. Shipment notification email template

Both are sharing same header and footer templates.
But when I recieve email order confirmation email showing images properly and shipment notification email images are not proper.

### How logo displayed:

[image]

Even I checked the email by debuging as html format I got two different image urls

1. https://myshopURL/static/version1536201509/frontend/namespace/module_name/en_GB/Magento_Email/logo_email.png (logo url of order confirmation & its correct)
2. https://myshopURL/pub/static/version1536201509/frontend/namespace/module_name/en_GB/Magento_Email/logo_email.png (logo url of shipment notification & its incorrect).

the word "pub" added extra in shipment notification email logo URL.

How these logo urls are different they share same header and footer email template?

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: In time when you was creating this templates did you change from developer mode to production? Try clear image cache.

Comment: @BartZalas, this is on production only. yes cleared cache.

Comment: I don't know I think you missed something in cleaning cache, Manually delete  I had same issue but I dont remember what helped.  Maybe this will help a little https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175455/how-does-magento-2-load-files-from-pub-static-directory   Try to change from production to developer and back to production.

Comment: @BartZalas, I will try with cache cleaning process and see. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

I had a simular problem. On viewing emails in magento backend, everything was fine. But if i send the email, there was this /pub directory in the url. I added a configuration to my env.php file in the app/etc folder and everything work fine now.
I think, the problem was, that our nginx use the pub folder as document root folder. [See the magento docs for more information.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html)
In this case, i had to set the following node to the array in my environment file:

```
'directories' => [
  'document_root_is_pub' => true,
],
```